# Esconder a barra de endereços da WebView

Tags: android, android-layout

Como precisei desenvolver um aplicativo do tipo `WebApp`, segui um tutorial e obtive sucesso (o tutorial utilizava a IDE  Android Studio 1.0.2). O aplicativo funciona satisfatoriamente, porém existe um detalhe que sei que esse tipo de aplicativo não deveria apresentar: **A barra de Endereço acima de todas as páginas do site (imagem)**. Utilizei a versão mais recente do Android Studio (**1.4.1**). Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver esse problema? Haveria uma maneira de a barra não aparecer durante a exibição do site? Já busquei em vários locais da Web mas as informações são sempre de versões anteriores e a estrutura do projeto não se iguala a do 1.4.1. Agradeço antecipadamente a ajuda!!!

[image: imagem 1]
[image: imagem 2]

Meu arquivo activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Meu arquivo content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Meu arquivo MyAppWebViewClient.java

```
package xxxx.wordpress;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/**
 * Created by Beto on 04/11/2015.
 */
//nona insercao de codigo apos MyAppWebViewClient
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

//criacao de classe e oitava insercao de codigo
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("xxx.com.br/wp")) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    }


}
```

Meu arquivo MainActivity.java

```
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
            import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
            import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.Menu;
            import android.view.MenuItem;
            import android.webkit.WebSettings;
            import android.webkit.WebView;
            import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

            public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


            private WebView mWebView;

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

                    // Enable Javascript
                    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();

                    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    mWebView.loadUrl("http://xxx.com.br/wp");

                    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
                    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

                    // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
                    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                    int id = item.getItemId();

                    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
                    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Não consigo ver as imagens. Teria como você postar parte do código da implementação? Você está usando o componente webView para renderizar seu webapp?

Comment: Olá Diego. Obrigado pela atenção! não sei se enviei as imagens corretamente (no corpo do texto) pois posso visualizá-las aqui. Desconfio, nos meus poucos conhecimentos ainda do Studio, que o ponto esteja no layout. E sim, estou usando o componente webView. Estou enviando os códigos do layout activity_main.xml e content_main.xml, alem do MyAppWebViewClient para voce dar uma olhada... muito obrigado!

Comment: Olá Diego. Conseguiu visualizar as imagens? vc viu o condigo que enviei? abs

Answer (score 1):

Adicione isso para desabilitar a barra de endereços:

```
WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: Olá Otto . Obrigado pela resposta .. mas essa linha de código já está em meu MainActivity.java. Como vc não indicou o local onde seria inserida, está no local correto? Obrigado e abs

Comment: Olá Otto. Está no local correto?

Comment: @RobertoGomes não identifiquei esta linha em seu código

Comment: Olá Otto. Obrigado pela atenção. A linha de comando que vc indicou está na MainActivity.java. Publiquei o código para vc dar seu parecer. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Tente inserir no *AndroidManifest.xml*, dentro da *activity* onde possui a *webview*:

```
<activity
.
.
.
android:theme="android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
     ou
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
>
</activity>
```

Comment: Obrigado Rodrigo. Vou tentar ! Valeu! Abraço!